# Google Sheets - Query date < doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

I'm using google sheets, and I found that this doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(CSV!1:1000,"select J, AA, AD where J<date'2004-01-01'")
```

But this does:

```
=QUERY(CSV!1:1000,"select J, AA, AD where J>date'1900-01-01' and not J>date'2004-01-01'")
```

Can someone please explain why I have to make my query more complicated to filter by date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(CSV!1:1000, "select J,AA,AD where J < date'2004-01-01' and J is not null", )
```

Comment: That worked...but why? I had 4 non-null results but none get returned unless the null check exists?

Comment: @user5061526 most likely they were returned but at the bottom of the sheet coz null rows came first/on top